# Flutter change position of AlertDialog in widget Tree

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating an `AlertDialog` deep in the widget tree of my app and use the Bloc package to emit an event by clicking on a button in the AlertDialog.
The problem is that the AlertDialog is positioned right below the MaterialApp in the widget tree  and so my BlocProvider can not be found in the context, because I define it further down the widget tree. I'm also not able to move the BlocProvider to be available globally because this provided bloc is dependend on a state that is only accessable further down the widget tree.
This is my function to call the AlertDialog with a TextField which emits an event `onChanged`:

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
    title: const Text("Create Patient Questionnaire"),
    content: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        const Text("Give your patient Questionnaire a name!"),
        UniversalTextField(
          prefixText: "Name",
          onChanged: (value) => context
              .read<CreatePQBloc>()
              .add(CreatePQDocumentNameChanged(documentName: value)),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

I would be interested to know if it's possible to change the position of the AlertDialog in the widget tree or if anybody knows a work-around for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed my problem by setting the parameter `useRootNavigator` of the `showDialog` to false, which results in the AlertDialog being positioned further down the widget tree and in my case, in scope to access all the necessary dependencies.

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  useRootNavigator: false,
  builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
    title: const Text("Create Patient Questionnaire"),
    content: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        const Text("Give your patient Questionnaire a name!"),
        UniversalTextField(
          prefixText: "Name",
          onChanged: (value) => context
              .read<CreatePQBloc>()
              .add(CreatePQDocumentNameChanged(documentName: value)),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

I could also just wrap the `Column` inside of the content with a BlocProvider but with my answer above I don't need to provide the bloc twice in the widget tree.